# php preg_match get numbers between two strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi I'm starting to learn php regex and have the following problem:
I need to extract the numbers inside $string.
The regex I use returns "NULL".

```
$string = 'Clasificación</a> (2194)  </li>';
$regex = '/Clasificación</a>((.*?))</li>/';
preg_match($regex , $string, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three problems with your regex:

- You aren't escaping the forward slash. You're using the forward slash as a delimiter, so if you want to use it as a literal character inside the expression, you need to escape it
- `((.*?))` doesn't do what you think it does. It creates two capturing groups -- one nested inside the other. I assume, you're trying to capture what's inside the parentheses. For that, you'll need to escape the `(` and `)` characters. The expression would become: `\((.*?)\)`
- Your expression doesn't handle whitespace. In the string you've given, there is whitespace between the `</a>` and the beginning of the number -- `</a> (2194)`. To ignore the whitespace and capture just the number, you need to use `\s` (which matches any whitespace character). For that, you need to write `\s*\((.*?)\)\s*`.

The final regular expression after fixing all the above errors, will look like:

```
$regex = '~Clasificación</a>\s*\((.*?)\)\s*</li>~';
```

Full code:

```
$string = 'Clasificación</a> (2194)  </li>';
$regex = '~Clasificación</a>\s*\((.*?)\)\s*</li>~';
preg_match($regex , $string, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "ClasificaciÃ³n (2194)  "
  [1]=>
  string(4) "2194"
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83844)

Answer (score 2):

You forget to espace `/` in your regex, since you're using the `/` as a delimiter:

```
$regex = '/Clasificación<\/a>((.*?))<\/li>/';
//        ^ delimiter    ^^               ^ delimiter
//                       ^^ / in a string which is escaped
```

Another way can be to change that delimiter, and then you will not have to escape it:

```
$regex = '#Clasificación<\/a>((.*?))<\/li>#';
```

See the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to escape out the special characters that you want to match:

```
$regex = '/Clasificación<\/a> \((.*?)\) <\/li>/'
```

and may want to make your match a little more specific where it matters (depending on your use case)

```
$regex = '/Clasificación<\/a>\s*\(([0-9]+)\)\s*<\/li>/';
```

that will allow for 0 or more spaces before or after the (1234) and only match if there are only numbers in the ()

I just tried this in php:

```
php > preg_match($regex , $string, $match);
php > var_dump($match);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "Clasificacin</a> (2194)  </li>"
  [1]=>
   string(4) "2194"
}
```